# How to move packages from the live image to a pool on the disc?

Tags: installation, package-management, live-usb, memory-usage

Currently I'm using UCK and trying to make Edubuntu 12.04.1 DVD launch installer on 256Mb RAM: [How to install Edubuntu on a system with low memory (256 Mb)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202526/how-to-install-edubuntu-on-a-system-with-low-memory-256-mb)

I was reading [release notes for 12.10](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/Edubuntu) and noticed that

> Language packs have now been moved off from the live image to a pool on the disc.

How can I move other packages correctly so they would be available to the live system and for installation without network access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct and long answer is in the wiki:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization#Modify_pool_structure_to_include_more_packages

But I've done it in the **wrong** hacky way without signing and with manual activation (which is enough for me):

1. Marked all needed packages for (re)installation in Synaptic and used `File > Generate download script`
2. Launched that script to download all the packages.
3. Unpacked the Alternate CD iso with UCK to `/home/username/tmp/remaster-iso` (default location). It stopped on trying to find SquashFS: there is none on Alternate CD.
4. Moved all the packages to `/home/username/tmp/remaster-iso/debs`.
5. Executed `sudo dpkg-scanpackages /home/username/tmp/remaster-iso/debs | gzip -9c > /home/username/tmp/remaster-iso/debs/Packages.gz`
6. Updated md5sum.txt:

   ```
   # find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum > md5sum.txt
   ```
7. Made the iso:

   ```
   sudo mkisofs -r -V "ubuntu_with_debs" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o dvd.iso /home/username/tmp/remaster-iso/
   ```
8. After installation I'll temporary replace `sources.list` with a single line:

   ```
   deb file:///media/ubuntu_with_debs/debs /
   ```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks, I'm verifying that it at least works for 12.04.1 right now and will add it later.