# Where is the source code for Alternate CD installer?

Tags: 12.04, source-code, alternate, debian-installer

AFAIU [debian-installer](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer) currently contains only documentation, where is the actual code for the Alternate CD installer?

Comment: is this what you were looking for? http://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/CheckOut

Comment: Looks like a proper one, will you create an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Debian Installer.

The alternate installer is created by Debian (upstream from Ubuntu).

Thus to look for the source, you'll need to pull this from the Debian repositories.

- http://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/CheckOut

According to debian:

> Debian Installer developers frequently checkout the whole tree for
> development.

Debian are transferring to Git - but the alternate installer is not completely migrated yet.

Two steps are required - checkout using `subversion` - and then checkout the sources from `git`

```
sudo apt-get install subversion, git, mr
svn co svn://svn.debian.org/svn/d-i/trunk debian-installer
```

Then pull the git repositories:

```
cd debian-installer/scripts
scripts/git-setup
mr -p checkout
```

Go for a coffee or two - each individual component (package) is checked-out - it will take quite some considerable amount of time over a slow link.

All the components are installed under the sub-folder `packages`

Comment: Any idea whether the Ubuntu devs make any changes to the upstream version?

Comment: @romandas - as far as I can gather - its the debian version they use and havent changed.  To be absolutely sure, you should drop in on the ubuntu-dev IRC or drop an email on their mailing list.